# How to update cart options in LaraveShoppingcart by Crinsane

Tags: php, laravel, cart

I'm using laravel cart by Crinsane
https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart

I wanna update options cart, I have many options inside, but I just want only one option to change, and I cannot do it

Here's my code

```
Cart::add([
'id' => 1, 
'name' => 'Keyboard', 
'qty' => 30, 
'price' => 399, 
'options' => [
'item_code' => 'KEY01', 
'dimension' => '30cm x 60cm', ...etc]
]);
```

and then I want to change options

Here's my code

```
Cart::update(
$rowId, [
'qty' => 60, 
'price' => 299, 
'options' => [
'item_code' => 'KEY02']
]);
```

and then the result options only item_code, and others are disappear
I want the others options still there, how to handle this?

Sorry for bad English

Thanks for Answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try by following code.

```
$item = Cart::get($rowId);
$option = $item->option->merge(['item_code' => 'KEY02']);

Cart::update(
    $rowId, [
    'qty' => 60, 
    'price' => 299, 
    'options' => $option
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is better way. and good solutions:

```
 public function updateCart(Request $request){
    $rid = $request->row_id;
    $qty = $request->qty;

    for($i = 0; $i< count($rid); $i++){
        $cart = Cart::get($rid[$i]);
        if ($cart->qty != $qty[$i]) {
            Cart::update(
                $rid[$i], [
                'qty' => $qty[$i],
                'options' => [
                    'image'            => $cart->options->image,
                    'description'      => $cart->options->description,
                    'unit_type'        => $cart->options->unit_type,
                    'color'            => $cart->options->color,
                    'print'            => $cart->options->print,
                    'design'           => $cart->options->design,
                    'discount_info'    => $cart->options->discount_info,
                    'discount_amount'  => $discountAmount * $qty[$i],
                ]
            ]);
        }
    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Cart update successfully');
}
```

Comment: Please explain your approach a little and especially why it is better.